How can I scan multiple objects at the same time using model target object recognition for Android?
Im currently trying to build an app for Android that can recognize small tokens (For a tabletop game). I'm linking data to these tokens once scanned using Vuforia's Model Targets. Everything is working inside of Unity, but I've run into a problem where I can't scan multiple objects at the same time with the Vuforia Model Targets library as stated in their documentation. I've seen that there is Multi Target tracking, but I'm not sure if this will have the desired effect as it states that its best practice is using multiple image targets.
I'm wondering if there is any other library that comes close, or where to start if I were to try and make this myself.
The only thing that comes close that I found is only included in a paid license: https://www.wikitude.com/multiple-object-tracking-augmented-reality/. Other than that I found nothing for Android.

Note that Wikitude is and end-of-life product.

Vuforia Model Target does not support active tracking of multiple targets at the same time. To enable detection out of a set of Model Targets you indeed need an Advance Model Target database. This, as you said, is a paid-for feature, however you can still use it with a free license plan for prototyping.
